# pandas: get the maximum value of a list with string numbers

Tags: string, pandas, list, max

I have a dataframe `df=pd.DataFrame({'xx':[['100','5','3'], ['5','40'], ['100']]})` and I would like to have the maximum of each list as a number. So I would like to get this:

```
xx
0   100
1   40
2   100
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another pandas method using [`series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to explode the series of lists into 1 series , then using [`series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) convert to int , then take max grouped by index:

```
df['max_col'] = df['xx'].explode().astype(int).max(level=0)

#or:-> df['xx'].explode().astype(int).groupby(level=0).max()
```

---

```
0    100
1     40
2    100
```

Comment: that's great. That also works with assign `df.assign(zz = lambda x: x.xx.explode().astype(int).max(level=0))`. Thanks a lot

Comment: @corianne1234 Glad I could help :)

Comment: Just one more question, if you had a list where there is a non numeric value in it, could you just set this to np.nan? maybe something with np.where()?

Comment: @corianne1234 you mean before finding max? then : `pd.to_numeric(df['xx'].explode(),errors='coerce').max(level=0).astype(int)` ? if max is a float leave out the `astype(int)`

Comment: perfect, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Convert values to integers and get `max` value:

```
df['xx'] = df['xx'].map(lambda x: max(int(y) for y in x))
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
df['xx'] = [max(int(y) for y in x) for x in df['xx']]
```

---

```
print(df)
    xx
0  100
1   40
2  100
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['max_xx'] = df['xx'].apply(lambda x: max(map(int, x)))
df['max_xx']
```

output:

```
0    100
1     40
2    100
```

---

if you want to use [pandas.DataFrame.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) you can use:

```
df.assign(max_xx=lambda x: [max(map(int, l)) for l  in x.xx])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to do this with assign? I tried ```df.assign(zz = lambda x: max(map(int, x.xx)))```

Comment: @corianne1234 yes you can use `df.assign` , if this was useful you can upvote or accept, thx!

Comment: I tried this (the above) but I get an error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list' `. So it doesn't work.

Comment: do  you run from jupyter?

Comment: @corianne1234 if you run from jupyter  you have to run only one time the cell, you may want to restart the kernel

Comment: eather you use `df.assign(xx=lambda x: [max(map(int, l)) for l  in x.xx])` or `df['xx'] = df['xx'].apply(lambda x: max(map(int, x)))` do not run them  both, the second one will change the `df` column, i recommand to restart the kernel and run `df.assign(xx=lambda x: [max(map(int, l)) for l  in x.xx])`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("weather_data.csv")
data_list = data["temp"].max()
print(data_list)
```

in the file of weather_data.csv we have a list which we called
temp if we need temp list maixmum value we can apply this method